# Memo Library - failed to find resources

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, memo

I am implementing the [Memo Library](https://github.com/zeoflow/memo) as stated in the documentation:

```
dependencies {
    def memo_version = "1.0.0"
    implementation("com.zeoflow:memo:$memo_version")
    implementation("com.zeoflow:memo-annotation:$memo_version")
    annotationProcessor("com.zeoflow:memo-compiler:$memo_version")
}
```

but when I am attempting to build the project this error pops-up.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find Memo.memo-lib:memo:unspecified.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.zeoflow:memo-annotation:1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was reported in [this issue](https://github.com/zeoflow/memo/issues/30) and was fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/zeoflow/memo/pull/31).

You can try the following version `1.1.1` which includes the fix for the reported bug or the latest release which is currently `1.1.7`.